# How can we set login page path

Tags: java, struts-1

I am working on web application in which we are using struts 1.3.Running application path is
https://subdomain.example.com/appliactionName.
When user enter above path then he reaches on login page.where appliactionName is name of our application.
how can we open login page if path is
 https://subdomain.example.com

Comment: You should add 'struts' tag with your question.

Comment: I don't know if this is even a setting/config you could do in your Struts-based Web application. This looks more of a container and/or Webserver's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make a uniqe session & check if you session is exist correspond to user then allow to home page or redirect to login page.

Comment: I have domain name like www.subdomain.mydomain.com". I want open the login.jsp by typing my domain name in the url from browser.

Comment: check starting of www.subdomain.mydomain.com that if session is set then prosid furter or else redirect to login.jsp

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set default page of your web application. If that is the case, you can set it by providing "welcome-file-list" tag in web.xml. for example:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/pages/login/login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Edit: If you want the login page to be opened from the main application url. You should add this welcome file list to that application's web.xml file.